# Use jQuery to insert hyphens into phone # in td fields

Tags: jquery, string

I have a table with a bunch of phone numbers queried from a database. I want to insert hyphens into the phone number so instead of: "0000000000" the user will see: "000-000-0000". Not very good at regex but this is what I've tried so far:

```
  $('.views-field-phone').each(function(){
      $(this).insertAfter(/(.{3})/g,"-1-")
      $(this).insertAfter(/(.{7})/g,"-1-")
  });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

maybe not optimal but...

```
 string = string.substring(0,3) + '-' + string.substring(3,6) + '-' + string.substring(6,10);
```

or for your case...

```
$('.views-field-phone').each(function(){
      var string = $(this).html();
      $(this).html(string.substring(0,3) + '-' + string.substring(3,6) + '-' + string.substring(6,10)) 
});
```

Comment: This makes sense to me. But the numbers are just coming out as: "  -  -   "

Comment: Working @ http://jsfiddle.net/ahCyg/ . is the html inside the element actually the phone number? (If you are ajaxing, you are going to have to do this on success handler instead of on page load, or else it will be formatting an empty string.)

Comment: figured it out. Sorry, working within drupal and found that the phone number was actually under two different classes in the dom and the phone numbers being displayed were in a different class. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple function that I use to format phone numbers, nothing special but gets the job done.

```
function formatPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
    var rawPhoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace(/-/g, "").replace(/ /g, "");
    if (isNaN(rawPhoneNumber)) {
        return null;
    }
    if (rawPhoneNumber.length == 10) {
        return "(" + rawPhoneNumber.substring(0, 3) + ") " + rawPhoneNumber.substring(3, 6) + "-" + rawPhoneNumber.substring(6, 10);
    }
    if (rawPhoneNumber.length == 11) {
        return rawPhoneNumber.substring(0, 1) + " (" + rawPhoneNumber.substring(1, 4) + ") " + rawPhoneNumber.substring(4, 7) + "-" + rawPhoneNumber.substring(7, 11);
    }
}
```

Test Cases:

```
$("body").append("<h1>" + formatPhoneNumber("1234567890") + "</h1>");
$("body").append("<h1>" + formatPhoneNumber("11234567890") + "</h1>");
$("body").append("<h1>" + formatPhoneNumber("11267890") + "</h1>");
```

Will Output:

```
<h1>(123) 456-7890</h1>
<h1>1 (123) 456-7890</h1>
<h1>undefined</h1>
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/MPD3p/).

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just use the javascript `substr()`? If the numbers are uniform, you can split it like this: 3-3-4 chars.